# Adding pre-defined text to a textarea based on a selectbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, select, textbox

I am making a website for my school in visual studio, and in a contact form written in html and javascript.

I have the names of all faculty members in a selectbox, and I want to make it so when a user selects a faculty member, the textarea, in which the user will then write his message, will automatically open with the name of the faculty member based on the user's selection.

Could someone please help me find a javascript library or tutorial?

Comment: What have you got/tried so far?

Comment: please provide your sample code

Comment: So far my code only includes the selectbox with values, a textarea, a submit button, and a validation function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectbox-id").change(function() {
  var optionSelected = $( "#selectbox-id option:selected" ).text();
  $("#textboxarea-id").text(optionSelected);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention using Jquery I'll provide a simple JavaScript answer.

```
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetName() {
            var sel = document.getElementById("Select1");
            var nm = '';
            if (sel.selectedIndex > -1) {
                nm = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            }
            document.getElementById("TextArea1").innerHTML = nm;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <select id="Select1" name="D1" onchange="SetName()">
         <option>Mr Green</option>
         <option>Mr White</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent! please accept my solution as an answer to the question then.